# Retrieve Azure Data Factory Service Identity Application ID

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-data-factory

I have created one Data Factory and Key Vault using C# Code, I would like to set Access Policy of Key Vault. 
For that I want data factory *"Service Identity Application ID"* (Highlighted in red in attached image) using C# code. 
How could I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the access token with the application id, hope [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity#asal) could help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this from C# code.

Here is a quick sample code that I wrote to get the Service Identity Application ID from C# code.

Pre-requisite is to install the following packages from your package manager console (Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory -Prerelease
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager -Prerelease
Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
```

After the packages are installed, use code below

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Rest;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

namespace GetDataFactory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Set variables
            string tenantID = "<your tenant ID>";
            string applicationId = "<your application ID>";
            string authenticationKey = "<your authentication key for the application>";
            string subscriptionId = "<your subscription ID where the data factory resides>";
            string resourceGroup = "<your resource group where the data factory resides>";
            string dataFactoryName = "<specify the name of data factory to create. It must be globally unique.>";

            // Authenticate and create a data factory management client
            var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantID);
            ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(applicationId, authenticationKey);
            AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc).Result;
            ServiceClientCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
            var client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };

            var myFactory = client.Factories.Get(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName);

            //Getting principal Id as you mentioned in question, but you can get more information from the Identity object as per your need.
            Guid? principalId = myFactory.Identity.PrincipalId;

        }
    }
}
```

Once you have all the identity information, you can update the access policy for the keyvault to give required permissions (like listing keys, get/list secrets etc.) to the application (whose Id you've highlighted in the image)

1. Use KeyVaultManagementClient class -

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.keyvault.keyvaultmanagementclient?view=azure-dotnet

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.keyvault.vaultsoperationsextensions.updateaccesspolicy?view=azure-dotnet
2. Use Fluent API -

   Look at this sample on Github - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-dotnet-manage-key-vaults

   ```
           Utilities.Log("Authorizing the application associated with the current service principal...");

           vault1 = vault1.Update()
                   .DefineAccessPolicy()
                       .ForServicePrincipal(SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION")).ClientId)
                       .AllowKeyAllPermissions()
                       .AllowSecretPermissions(SecretPermissions.Get)
                       .AllowSecretPermissions(SecretPermissions.List)
                       .Attach()
                   .Apply();

           Utilities.Log("Updated key vault");
           Utilities.PrintVault(vault1);

           //============================================================
           // Update a key vault

           Utilities.Log("Update a key vault to enable deployments and add permissions to the application...");

           vault1 = vault1.Update()
                   .WithDeploymentEnabled()
                   .WithTemplateDeploymentEnabled()
                   .UpdateAccessPolicy(vault1.AccessPolicies[0].ObjectId)
                       .AllowSecretAllPermissions()
                       .Parent()
                   .Apply();

           Utilities.Log("Updated key vault");
           // Print the network security group
           Utilities.PrintVault(vault1);
   ```
3. Use Rest API

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/vaults/updateaccesspolicy

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It is very usefull. However, It couldn't solve my problem. Actually I want code to retreive Azure Data Factory Application ID( Highlighted in image) using C# code/

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Bhavesh Kashikar. I have edited my answer to add a code sample at the beginning, which solves your problem very specifically. Please take a look now.

Comment: @Bhavesh Kashikar Did you get a chance to use the updated code for getting to Azure Data Factory Application ID?

Comment: I have used same code, it is giving me PrincipleID, but not ObjectID (Highlighted in above image). myFactory.Identity will give me PrincipleId and TenantId, which is linked to Service Identity Id and Service Identity Tenant, but I could not find property which is linked to Service Identity Application ID

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the app id of an existing ADF, you need to do 2 trips.

The first is to retrieve the service identity for resource manager.  @rohit's first code block does this in c#.  This retrieves the object ID of the principal, not the app ID which is an attribute of that object.

The second is to retrieve the application ID from active directory via RM.  You can then use this to assign access policy.  For example, in powershell you would do this:

First Step:

```
$principal = (Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName "yourRG" -Name yourADF).identity.PrincipalId
```

then second step...

```
$appId = (Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $principal).ApplicationId
```

The c# equivilent should be easy to figure out from this.